# Apache reverse proxy to serve node

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy, proxypass

I want to setup reverse proxy so http://www.carolinatransparency.com/form is used to serve my node app that is running on http://localhost.com:5000.

The problem is that there seems to be some sort of collision because the .conf file for carolinatransparency.com also handles the /form route and doesn't allow the reverse proxy. Is there a way to disable this specific path in `carolinatransparency.com.conf`

```
ServerName www.carolinatransparency.com
ServerAlias carolinatransparency.com
ServerAdmin yasin@generatedesign.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/carolinatransparency.com

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

`form.votetracker.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /form http://localhost:5000
    ProxyPassReverse /form http://localhost:5000

    ServerName http://www.carolinatransparency.com/form/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Servername directive does not take a URL, just a host name, fixt that first. Also you can't define ServerName with the same name in two different contexts, so define it once and host all needed directives there.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah moving the proxy rules to the first virtual host fixed the issue.